# How to find the time derivative of temparature by solving the relativistic Boltzmann equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, cosmology, temperature, boltzmann-equation

I am trying to find the temporal derivatives of the temperature by solving the relativistic Boltzmann equation. However, it didn't turn out as simple as I thought.

The relativistic Boltzmann equation without collision term is given by

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=p^a \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^a}+\frac{\mathrm{d}p^a}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\frac{\partial f}{\partial p^a}=0,$$

where $\tau$ is the Affine parameter for the geodesic. To put it in more detail on my trial, for instance, in the Robertson-Walker spacetime, this becomes

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+Hp\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=0.$$

When I put the equilibrium distribution function $f=\exp(-E/k_B T)$ into the equation,

$$\frac{\partial_t E}{E}-\frac{\partial_t T}{T}=H (\frac{p}{E})^2.$$

This coincides with the energy-momentum relation $E^2 = (ap)^2 + m^2$ only if $\partial_t T=0$, where $a$ is a scale factor. But it is known that $\dot{T}\sim a^{-n}$, where for radiation $n=1$, for matter $n=2$, for dust $n=0$. I guess that this is because $\partial_t T \neq \dot{T}$ and $T$ should not depend on the size of the momentum. So I expanded $\dot{T}$ as

$$\dot{T}=\partial_t T + \partial_a T \frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}t}=aH\partial_a T,$$

but I have no idea how to proceed further.

I know how to derive $\dot{T}\sim a^{-n}$ using the equation

$$\frac{\dot{T}}{T}=H\frac{\partial p / \partial T}{\partial \rho / \partial T},$$

after obtaining $p, \rho$ by integrating the Boltzmann equation or the distribution function directly. However, I found it a bit complicated if the distribution is not in equilibrium form or if the metric is not the isotropic and homogenous cosmological one. Hence my question is, **is there any way I can obtain the time derivative of the temperature**(for example, by finding $\partial_a T$ in the case above), **without the direct integration of the Boltzmann equation**, to bypass the issue I have mentioned?